# How to interpret pg_stat_user_indexes and pg_statio_user_indexes results?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have this query to analyze index usage in Postgres:

```
SELECT idx.*
     , idxio.idx_blks_read
     , idxio.idx_blks_hit 
  FROM pg_stat_user_indexes idx
  JOIN pg_statio_user_indexes idxio
 USING (indexrelid)
 ORDER BY idx_scan;
```

I understand I need to compare "snapshots" of results, i.e. I need to execute this query and save the results, and some time later after some usage I will execute again and compare results.

But I want to know how to interpret some pattern of values from these columns

- idx_scan
- idx_tup_read
- idx_tup_fetch
- idx_blks_read
- idx_blks_hit

I don't want to know the meaning/definition of these columns, but what are the (most common) patterns of values will exhibit a "good", "bad" or "maybe" index.

As example of patterns, I noticed for PK indexes is common `idx_scan = idx_tup_read = idx_tup_fetch`.
Other common pattern is very high `idx_tup_read` (millions) and very small or even zero `idx_tup_fetch`.
Yet other pattern is high `idx_scan` but zero `idx_tup_read` and `idx_tup_fetch` (some of these with high both `idx_blks_read` and `idx_blks_hit`).

Comment: Those tables are almost entirely useless.  You should identify problems and then work to solve them, not identify imaginary solutions and then seek out problems they solve.